# Juggling Animations and View Hierarchy in React

Tags: javascript, animation, reactjs

I'm having some frustrations with React because the view hierarchy is ruining my animations.

I have a `<Layout>` component that setups a tab-nav layout and its children are placed within the content portion of the layout. It is a pure component that has props for `title`, `setTab`, and `currentTab`.

If I were thinking about this from a view hierarchy perspective and one-directional data-flow, I would have the layout be the child of each view so the view could set the title, current tab, and `setTab` could be delegated to its parent.

This basically what I am doing:

```
var A = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    setTab: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Layout title="A Page" currentTab="A" setTab={this.props.setTab}>
        This is A
      </Layout>           
    )
  }
});
```

Now you can use React Router or something for the tabs, but right now, I just have a simple top-level component switching tabs with its state:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      currentTab: 'A'
    }
  },
  setTab: function(name) {
    this.setState({currentTab:name})
  },
  render: function() {
    var component = false
    if (this.state.currentTab == 'A') {
      return <A setTab={this.setTab}/>
    } else {
      return <B setTab={this.setTab}/>
    }
  }
});
```

This is all fine and dandy until you want to start adding some animations.

In my `<Layout>` component, I have a highlight block that I want to animate left to right when switching between tabs.

```
        <div className="tabbar">
          <div className={"highlight " + this.props.currentTab}></div>
          <div className="tabs">
            <div className="tab" onClick={() => {this.props.setTab('A')}}>A</div>
            <div className="tab" onClick={() => {this.props.setTab('B')}}>B</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS for that animation:

```
.highlight {
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: left .25s ease-in-out;
}
.highlight.A {
    left: 0;
}
.highlight.B {
    left: 50%;
}
```

I'm also trying to animate the Layout's title using a the `React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup` but I think the issue is the same:

The problem here seems to be that the `<Layout>` component is entirely re-rendered each time because the root of the render tree (`<A/>` and `<B/>`) is changing.

So the question now, is how do I invert the view hierarchy so that `<Layout>` doesnt keep getting re-rendered so the animation can work?

Note: In a less contrived example, the layout may also get other props from the `<A/>` such as onClick handlers.

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating my frustrations:

https://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/3rupb0og/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured something out that works, but I'm not sure if this is a best practice so I'd really appreciate some feedback before I conclude that this is the answer.

I've come up with a concept of a `stitch` as a way of *stitching* functions through the component hierarchy. This will allow me to set the state of a parent component from the child component.

```
function stitch() {
  return {
    to: (f) => {
      this.func = f
    },
    from: () => {
      this.func.apply(null, arguments)
    }
  }
}
```

So now my `<Layout>` looks like this:

```
var Layout = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    currentTab: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onTab: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    stitchTitle: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      title: ''
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.props.stitchTitle((title) => {
      this.setState({title})
    })
  },
  // ...
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
var A = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    setTitle: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.props.setTitle('Page A')
  },
  //...
}
```

And all we have to do is *stitch* them together.

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      currentTab: 'A'
    }
  },
  setTab: function(name) {
    this.setState({currentTab:name})
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.titleStitch = stitch()
  },
  render: function() {
    var view = false
    if (this.state.currentTab == 'A') {
      view = <A setTitle={this.titleStitch.from}/>
    } else {
      view = <B setTitle={this.titleStitch.from}/>
    }
    return (
      <Layout currentTab={this.state.currentTab} onTab={this.setTab} stitchTitle={this.titleStitch.to}>
        {view}
      </Layout>  
    )
  }
});
```

And sure enough it works! Here's the JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/bLtuLdwh/